# 3D graph using three.js

Tags: javascript, graph, three.js, 3d

I have to plot a 3D scatter graph using *three.js*. I tried the following code which I have mentioned. The code is working but the graph looks similar to a 2D graph. The position of the camera can be adjusted to make it look like a 3D graph but I am not able to map the exact position of the camera.

```js
let scene,camera,renderer,axes;
let set = [];

let createGeometry = function()
{
    set.push(new THREE.Vector3(5,5,10) );
    set.push(new THREE.Vector3(10,15,17));
    set.push(new THREE.Vector3(15,20,12));
    set.push(new THREE.Vector3(20,16,10));
    set.push(new THREE.Vector3(17,9,19));
    set.push(new THREE.Vector3(23,2,13));

    let setgeometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry().setFromPoints(set);
    let setmaterial = new THREE.PointsMaterial({ color : 0xff0000 , size : 10 ,sizeAttenuation : false});
    let plot = new THREE.Points( setgeometry , setmaterial );

    scene.add(plot);

}    
let init = function(){
    scene = new THREE.Scene;
    scene.background = new THREE.Color(0x000000);

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(25 , window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight , 1 , 1000);
    camera.position.set(20,10,90);

    let axes =new THREE.AxesHelper(25);
    scene.add(axes);

    createGeometry();

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth,window.innerHeight);
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

};

let mainloop = function(){
    
    renderer.render(scene , camera);
    requestAnimationFrame(mainloop);
};

init();
mainloop();
```

```css
html, body {margin: 0; padding: 0;overflow: hidden;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.117.1/build/three.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: where is your canvas?

Comment: What do you mean with "not able to map the exact position of the camera"? Can you please explain in more detail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your computer monitor is a 2D plane with only pixels in the X,Y axis, so without motion you're going to run the risk of accidentally making your chart look flat. If you want to make the third dimension more evident, you should just add some animation. In the demo below I'm rotating around the center by updating the camera position on each frame with:

```
camera.position.set(
    Math.sin(time) * 70,
    70,
    Math.cos(time) * 70);
camera.lookAt(0,0,0);
```

```js
let scene,camera,renderer,axes;
let set = [];

let createGeometry = function()
{
    set.push(new THREE.Vector3(5,5,10) );
    set.push(new THREE.Vector3(10,15,17));
    set.push(new THREE.Vector3(15,20,12));
    set.push(new THREE.Vector3(20,16,10));
    set.push(new THREE.Vector3(17,9,19));
    set.push(new THREE.Vector3(23,2,13));

    let setgeometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry().setFromPoints(set);
    let setmaterial = new THREE.PointsMaterial({ color : 0xff0000 , size : 10 ,sizeAttenuation : false});
    let plot = new THREE.Points( setgeometry , setmaterial );

    scene.add(plot);

}    
let init = function(){
    scene = new THREE.Scene;
    scene.background = new THREE.Color(0x000000);

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(25 , window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight , 1 , 1000);

    let axes =new THREE.AxesHelper(25);
    scene.add(axes);

    createGeometry();

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth,window.innerHeight);
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

};

let mainloop = function(t){
    let time = t / 1000;
    camera.position.set(
        Math.sin(time) * 70,
        70,
        Math.cos(time) * 70);
    camera.lookAt(0,0,0);
    renderer.render(scene , camera);
    requestAnimationFrame(mainloop);
};

init();
mainloop(0);
```

```css
html, body {margin: 0; padding: 0;overflow: hidden;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.117.1/build/three.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: It makes the camera rotate in a circle. Try playing with the values to see what each line does.